# How to take in a number and divide it into three parts positive or negative, whole number and fractions

Tags: c, sorting, modular

In a school assignment we where supposed to write a program that takes in a number and divide it in three parts:
1. Check if the number is positive or negative
2. whole number (magnitude)
3. fractional parts

The requirement is that there should be a own function called separate that has input and output parameter.

For example: if you type in 23.639, the program should sort of out and print out:
Sign: +
Whole number magnitude: 23
Fractional parts: 0.639

QUESTIONS:
1.The function for sorting out whether the number is positive or negative brings forth the wrong answer when typing in a negative number. It also posts wrong character. I have tried different data types, like int, char and float, but none seem to work. Any tip on how to solve this are greatly appreciated, cause I think I'm blinded by my own errors...

2.The function separating decimals from whole numbers (fractions) won't subtract the whole number away from the decimals, so I am stuck with whole number. Can anyone spot my error here?

---

*** UPDATE ***

I managed to solve the questions at hand, and did the terrible n00b error of editing the code I first posted in this question.
I have now edited the code once more to hold the original errors as best as I can remember. The right code is posted as an answer below.

Sorry for the rookie error.

```
/*
Author: Thorbjørn Elvestad
Student ID: *****
E-mail: drommevandrer@gmail.com


This program take in number typed in by the user, and then divide it into three parts.

SIGN: '+' or '-'
Whole number: Show number as a whole number
Fraction: Show fractions 

The program uses function to sort out the number, and print out the result*/

/* Declaring libraries */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Declaring functions */
double sorting_sign(char x);
double sorting_whole(double x);
double sorting_fract(double x, int y);



/* Calling main function */
int main()
{
    double num, fractures; /* declaring variables */
    int sign_sorted, part;
    double whole_sorted;

    printf("LET ME TELL YOU SOME INTERESTING STUF ABOUT YOUR NUMBER!\n\n");
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    sign_sorted = sorting_sign(num); /* Calling the function that sorts out if this number is '+' or '-' */
    whole_sorted = sorting_whole(num); /* Calling the function separating whole number from decimals */
    fractures = sorting_fract(num, num); /* Calling the function removing the whole number from the fractures */

    printf("Sign: %c\nWhole: %0.lf\nFraction: %f", sign_sorted, whole_sorted, fractures);

    return 0;
}


/* Function for sorting of if number is '+' or '-' */
double sorting_sign(char x)
{
    int sign;

    /* true if number is less than 0 */
    if(x < 0.0){sign = '-';}

    /* true if number is greater than 0 */
    else if(x > 0.0){sign = '+';}

    return (sign);
}


/* Function for sorting out the whole number */
double sorting_whole (double x)
{
    int whole;

    whole = x;

    return (whole);
}

/* Function for sorting out the fractions */
double sorting_fract(double x)
{
    int whole;
    double fract;
    whole = y;
    fract = x - whole;


    return (fract, whole);
}
```

Comment: Is `(fract, whole)` a double?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &num);` --> `scanf("%lf", &num);` and similarly `printf("DEBUGGING 1 (in main): Your number is %d ...` should use type `%f`.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse... that did the trick. Thank you... I had a feeling I had manage to run into a maze of data types somewhere, and messed up the code in my search to fix it all. However, I did think the problem where in the functions, and not my scanf, but that actually made a lot of sense :)

Comment: sorry, rookie mistake.... I have edited the faulty code back as good as I remember, and edited the original questions to be more readable and understandable. The answer to the both questions and including fully working program is posted as an fully answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared your `sorting_sign` function to return a `double`, when you're returning an `int` set to the value of a `char`... sort your types out.

Comment: Indeed, sort your types out - wrong format types for `scanf` and `printf` too.

Comment: Thanks... I did mess up with the data types in my search to sort it all out, and it really backfired me into a total mess... Thanks for tip, both of you :)... printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num); and changing that function into int did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
For future reference I hereby post the code for the fully working program:

```
/*
Author: Thorbjørn Elvestad
Student ID: *****
E-mail: drommevandrer@gmail.com


This program take in number typed in by the user, and then divide it into three parts.

SIGN: '+' or '-'
Whole number: Show number as a whole number
Fraction: Show fractions 

The program uses function to sort out the number, and print out the result*/

/* Declaring libraries */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Declaring functions */
int sorting_sign(int x);
double sorting_whole(double x);
double sorting_fract(double x);



/* Calling main function */
int main()
{
double num, fractures; /* declaring variables */
int sign_sorted, part;
double whole_sorted;

printf("LET ME TELL YOU SOME INTERESTING STUF ABOUT YOUR NUMBER!\n\n");
printf("Enter your number: ");
scanf("%lf", &num);

sign_sorted = sorting_sign(num); /* Calling the function that sorts out if this number is '+' or '-' */
whole_sorted = sorting_whole(num); /* Calling the function separating whole number from decimals */
fractures = sorting_fract(num); /* Calling the function removing the whole number from the fractures */

printf("Sign: %c\nWhole: %0.lf\nFraction: %f", sign_sorted, whole_sorted, fractures);

return 0;
}


/* Function for sorting of if number is '+' or '-' */
int sorting_sign(int x)
{
int sign;

/* true if number is less than 0 */
if(x < 0.0){sign = '-';}

/* true if number is greater than 0 */
else if(x > 0.0){sign = '+';}

return (sign);
}


/* Function for sorting out the whole number */
double sorting_whole (double x)
{
int whole;

whole = x;

return (whole);
}

/* Function for sorting out the fractions */
double sorting_fract(double x)
{
int whole;
double fract;
whole = (int)x;
fract = x - whole;


return (fract);
}
```